# Apply a specific function for two columns in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with two columns, each row contains a list of elements. I'm trying to find set difference between two columns for each row using `pandas.apply` method.

My df for example

```
           A              B
0     ['a','b','c']     ['a']
1     ['e', 'f', 'g']   ['f', 'g']
```

So it should look like this:

```
df.apply(set_diff_func, axis=1)
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
0      ['b','c']
1      ['e']
```

I can make it using `iterrows`, but I've once read, that it's better to use `apply` when it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
df.apply(lambda row: list(set(row['A']) - set(row['B'])), axis = 1)
```

or

```
(df['A'].apply(set) - df['B'].apply(set)).apply(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the function you need, you can change the name of the columns with the `col1` and `col2` arguments by passing them to the `args` option in `apply`:

```py
def set_diff_func(row, col1, col2):
    return list(set(row[col1]).difference(set(row[col2])))
```

This should return the required result:

```py
>>> dataset = pd.DataFrame(
    [{'A':['a','b','c'], 'B':['a']},
     {'A':['e', 'f', 'g'] , 'B':['f', 'g']}])
>>> dataset.apply(set_diff_func, axis=1, args=['A','B'])
0    [c, b]
1       [e]
```